# Identify automatically generated member functions

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Special member functions are "functions which the compiler will automatically generate if they are used, but not declared explicitly by the programmer".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions

Details are in §12 of the C++11 Standard:

> The default constructor (12.1), copy constructor and copy assignment operator (12.8), move constructor and move assignment operator (12.8), and destructor (12.4) are special member functions. [*Note*: The implementation will implicitly declare these member functions for some class types when the program does not explicitly declare them. The implementation will implicitly define them if they are odr-used (3.2). See 12.1,12.4 and 12.8. —*end note*]

What known methods can identify all generated special member functions upon compilation?

My preferred compilers are gcc and clang.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I would like a systematic way of revealing use of these defaults, especially default copy constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++11, header [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) defines a set of following functions:

```
is_constructible
is_default_contructible
is_copy_contructible
is_move_contructible
is_assignable
is_copy_assignable
is_move_assignable
is_destructible
```

You can use them to test for existence of implicitly generated methods at compile time,
eg.:

```
std::is_constructible<ClassName>::value
```